# export a template function of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, boost-python

I can't figure out the reason why my code below does not compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/class.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

template<std::size_t Tsize>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {}

    ~MyClass()
    {}

    template<typename data_t>
    void Sum(data_t* result, const data_t* v1, const data_t* v2)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < Tsize; ++i)
            result[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
    }
};

template<std::size_t Tsize>
void AddMyClass()
{
    typedef MyClass<Tsize> MyClassType;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "MyClass" << Tsize;

    bp::class_<MyClassType, boost::noncopyable>
    (ss.str().c_str(), bp::init<>())
    .def("SumInt", &MyClassType::Sum<int>)
    .def("SumDouble", &MyClassType::Sum<double>)
    ;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myclass)
{
    AddMyClass<1>();
    AddMyClass<2>();
    AddMyClass<3>();
    AddMyClass<4>();
    AddMyClass<5>();
}
```

The compiler throws the error

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
```

Removing the template argument of AddMyClass removes the error, but it will make the code longer, because each type of MyClass has to be exported.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you try `template< typename Tsize = std::size_t >`?

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

Missing `template` keyword:

```
.def("SumInt", &MyClassType::template Sum<int>)
.def("SumDouble", &MyClassType::template Sum<double>)
```

Comment: aha, that's the one.